# Primefaces 3.5 selectCheckBoxMenu call event onShow

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I have a page with several conditions and when I try to open selectCheckBoxMenu I want the method to be called from server but I get something strange. List with my items doesn't show and twitches all times.

```
<p:selectCheckboxMenu id="scroll"
                                              value="#{adminManageTournamentController.teamListSelected}"
                                              label="#{msg.teams}" filter="true" filterText="Filter"
                                              filterMatchMode="startsWith" panelStyle="width:auto"
                                             onShow="sourceFilterCommand();">
                            <f:selectItems value="#{adminManageTournamentController.teamList}"
                                           var="team" itemLabel="#{team.name}"
                                           itemValue="#{team.id}"/>
                            <p:column>
                                #{team.name}
                            </p:column>
                            <p:remoteCommand name="sourceFilterCommand" update="scroll"
                                             actionListener="#{adminManageTournamentController.selectTeamsByConditions}"/>
                        </p:selectCheckboxMenu>
```

Did I choose correct way for decision? How to get rid of the twitching list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably reason of those twitches is endless loop. When your `p:selectCheckboxMenu` is shown remote command is called, and `p:selectCheckboxMenu` is updated and it is shown again and remote command is called again... And this never ends. It is strange that you are updating component in `onShow`. You probably should do this in moment when conditions for updating are changed, this is not place where you should update component. If this `p:selectCheckboxMenu` is for example dependent on some `p:selectOneMenu` update it when value of `p:selectOneMenu` is changed.

Comment: I doesn't have selectItem and when I open page with defaults values without changing defaults from which depends selectCheckBox I should get data set.

Comment: I added this just as example. If you are updating `p:selectCheckboxMenu` this means that you are changing something inside remote command method. Otherwise why would you update it.